How does a copper oxide solar cell work?
I‘ve always been told that you need a PN junction for a solar cell to work. But then how do copper oxide solar cells work, if there is no doping?

This is interesting question in photovoltaics. Yes, you are right. It is neccessary to form p-n junction to create photovoltaic effect in solar cells. I think that you know well how solar cell works and importance of p-n junction in solar cells to form internal electric field in order to seperate a electron-hole pairs (exitons) and direct them towards contacts.
Mainly, in literatures, in forming of p-n junctions, doping is used. For example, to form n type or p type silicon, we need to dope Phosphosrous atoms or Boron atoms to instrinsic silicon. But, in case of Cu2O, you have to think in material science point of view. Is it possible to form p-n junction without doping? Yes of course, it is possible. For example, Cu2O is generally p type semiconductor with direct bands gap. But depending on sythesis method, you can get n type Cu2O too. So p type of Cu2O is due to precence of Cu vacancies and n type is due to precence of Oxygen vacancies. If in you material, concentration of Cu vacancies are greater than that of oxygen vancies, it means that your structure is p type Cu2O. Opposite difference of concentration of oxygen and Cu creates n type Cu2O.
Because of this phenomenon, you can create p-n homojunction Cu2O solar cell without doping external atoms.

Is there some source on similar materials?
